# Treat a string as binary in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, binary

I have a string coming from a database, for example `0b0101000`.

I'd like to cast it to a binary value, in order to apply byte operations on it, like `0b01011000 & (1<<0 | 1<<4)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings support a [`.to_i(base)` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000787):

```
irb(main):016:0> b="0b01" ; b.to_i(2)
=> 1
irb(main):017:0> b="0b10" ; b.to_i(2)
=> 2
irb(main):018:0> b="0b11" ; b.to_i(2)
=> 3
irb(main):019:0> b="0b1111" ; b.to_i(2)
=> 15
```

Comment: How could I ever miss that ? Thanks.